# Cannot access classic asp files through IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Windows 2003 IIS 6
I have a virtual directory called offline. I can access the default.htm file via

```
http://localhost/offline/default.htm
```

but

```
http://localhost/offline/config.asp
```

returns with "The page cannot be displayed".
I can see the file through the IIS manager interface. In the application configuration .asp is listed as an application extension. Execute permissions on the virtual directory are "scripts only"
So the questions is Why won't the file display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IIS Manager under the server node in the tree view select the "Web Service Extensions" node.

On the right hand side ensure "Active Server Pages" is "Allowed".  You should have "Server Side Includes" allowed as well.